# Java Process.getInputStream() does not return data until end of execution

Tags: java, process, inputstream

I've been trying to create a Java program that eventually will be used to control a Wi-Fi access point in Linux using hostapd and dnsmasq packages (those are the access point, and the DNS/DHCP server, respectively).

It is critical that I can read hostapd's StdOut while it is executing, as it returns data that must be parsed to display important data to the user.

For that, I am using the following code:

```
// Start access point
MainFrame.instance.setStatus("Starting access point...");
List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

// sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf
cmd.add("/usr/bin/sudo");
cmd.add("/usr/sbin/hostapd");
cmd.add("/etc/hostapd.conf");

ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder();
ps.command(cmd);
ps.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = ps.start();

//Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf");

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
MainFrame.instance.setStatus("Running");
MainFrame.instance.setRunning(true);
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    output += (line + '\n');
    if (line.contains("AP-STA-CONNECTED")) {
        addClientToList(line);
    } else if (line.contains("AP-STA-DISCONNECTED")) {
        removeClientFromList(line);
    }
}
input.close();
```

However, no data is returned until hostapd is terminated. Data is displayed correctly if the same command (`sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf`) is executed by the user in the terminal. Why is it that I can't get the data from the InputStream?

I'm fairly new to Java, so there might be some very obvious errors here that I've missed, but if so, please tell me :)

Comment: Just a guess but readLine terminates on linefeed/carriage return (one or both) or null, maybe there are no cr/lf being returned? so readline is only returning when hostapd is terminated?

Comment: Nope, I'm sure it returns with some kind of cr or lf. I edited my code slightly to also add the line to an ArrayList<String>, here are the results: http://i.imgur.com/JgzhOmL.png

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After you added a screenshot, this doesn't seem to be the problem. Then you are probably blocking the AWT Event Thread, so it can't repaint the GUI. The GUI only updates when the AWT Thread is free. In order to solve that problem, execute your code in a separate thread.

```
new Thread("Data Fetcher", new Runnable()
{
     public void run()
     {
          // Here comes your original code you posted.
     }
}). start();
```

---

However, as soon as your application comes in production, keep this in mind:

`sudo` is most likely prompting for the password of the administrator. I can remember a `gksudo` instead that would pop up a dialog and lets you enter the password.

I never tested it, but it might be possible that writing the password through `p.getOutputStream()`, followed by a newline and a flush could work.

Comment: I've run the IDE as root/superuser, which in turn will launch Java as superuser, which in turn will make the Java application be able to launch sudo commands without requiring a password. I should have put this in the main post, sorry for not being clear enough :) Also, the process wouldn't have given back any output at all if it had asked for a password, as "hostapd" wouldn't have run in the first place.

Comment: As of your edit, I don't know if this works; http://pastebin.com/Qp9bm4qX is being invoked as a `Runnable hotspotLauncher = new HotspotLauncher();` followed by `Thread launcherThread = new Thread(hotspotLauncher);`, setDaemon to true and start(). That's what I'm doing now.